# WinRT binding an Image to a string or StorageFile

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I am trying to display an image from a `StorageFile` after selecting it from a `FilePicker`.  Since the `Source` of an `Image` has to be either a `URI` or an `ImageSource`, I am trying to get either of those from the `StorageFile`.

I am having a hard time getting data binding to work on an `Image` in XAML.  I have tried the following:

```
<Image Width="300" 
       Height="300" 
       x:Name="LogoImage">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

This way doesn't work, as the `Path` property of a `StorageFile` is not a `URI`.  Also, I can't bind directly to the `StorageFile` itself, as it is not an `ImageSource`.

I tried to use this method:

```
public async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(StorageFile storageFile)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = bitmapImage;
    return image;
}
```

But, it returns a `Task<Image>`, which is also not an `ImageSource` or `URI`.  It seems like it should be something more straightforward than what I am trying to do, but I am just not seeing it.  Also, I have tried just specifying a file in the XAML for the `Image.Source` and it works fine.  I just haven't been able to link it up based on the selected file from the `FilePicker`.

My ultimate goal is: select a file from `FilePicker`, update the `ImageSource` of the displayed `Image`, encode to base64 for storage in database.  Then later, load existing base64 string from database, convert back to `Image` to be displayed.

**Edit:**

I was able to accomplish this task using the solution I posted below.  Thanks in great part to Jerry Nixon's blog post: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/reading-and-writing-base64-in-windows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this question looking for an answer, what I ultimately ended up doing for my situation, is take the `StorageFile` that is selected from the `FilePicker`, encode that as a base64 string (which I will save to my database for later retrieval).

Once I have the base64 string, I can decode that string into an `ImageSource` to set in code-behind.  Here is my full `ButtonClick` event handler:

```
private async void ChooseImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    filePicker.SettingsIdentifier = "picker1";
    filePicker.CommitButtonText = "Open File to Process";

    var files = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

    if (files.Count > 0)
    {
        // encode the storage file to base64
        var base64 = await Encoding.ToBase64(files[0]);

        // asynchronously save base64 string to database
        // ...

        // decode the base64 and set the image source
        LogoImage.Source = await Encoding.FromBase64(base64);
    }
}
```

The base64 encoding/decoding I found at the great Jerry Nixon's blog here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/reading-and-writing-base64-in-windows.html

Comment: I agree. I would definitely appreciate some feedback on a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to set the source in code behind instead of using a binding as it would let you handle things like cancellation in case the ImagePath gets updated while the previous image is still loading.

Alternatively, you could create a bitmap, start a task of loading it and return before that task is complete, e.g.

```
public Image GetImage(StorageFile storageFile)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    GetImageAsync(bitmapImage, storageFile);

    // Create an image or return a bitmap that's started loading
    var image = new Image();
    image.Source = bitmapImage;

    return image ;
}

private async Task GetImageAsync(BitmapImage bitmapImage, StorageFile storageFile)
{
    using (var stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        await bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I will try that out tonight.  I will be displaying the `FilePicker` and setting the source in code-behind for the details page of my application, but in the parent page, I am still hoping to be able to use binding for a `GridView`.  

I suppose I could do that in the code-behind as well by setting the source in the `OnNavigatedTo` event or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I ended up going a different route for my purposes.  I needed my images to be encoded in base64 anyway for saving to a `string` property into the database.  I posted my solution below.